# How can a network-wide suspension be not entirely network-wide?

Tags: support, network-wide-suspension

Today I noticed [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134300) is suspended network-wide according to the text on the profile page:

> [image: network-wide]

No other SE sites are visible in this profile page, only MSE.

> [image]

Just out of curiosity I went to the Wayback Machine and found the [user's old profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225223906/http://meta.stackexchange.com/users/134300/jeremy-banks). That snapshot of the profile page already contains two sites in the community list (MSE and SO), hence visiting the current version of SO profile I expected to see the profile page of suspended network-wide user. But the [user is not suspended](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1114/). How is this possible?

Comment: For science he found a bug ....

Comment: Although this post is a duplicate here, you could try asking this on Meta.SO about the specific reasons for this user, as @Glorfindel suggested.

Comment: @MEEisJohannGambolputty... I've just asked globally [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323437/what-is-the-purpose-of-network-wide-suspension-if-the-regular-mod-can-unsuspend?noredirect=1&lq=1) for the reason of such actions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*How* this is possible is quite simple; a network-wide suspension is simply copied to all sites, not unlike a user can copy the contents of their profile page to all sites. It's then possible to modify this on a site-by-site basis; that happens here as well. A ♦ moderator or Community Manager unsuspended the user on Stack Overflow.

*Why* this was done is a private matter between the moderators/CMs and the user.

Comment: Why not hammer it?

Comment: Didn't realize it was a duplicate; and a CM might or might not want to address the case of this specific user.