# Network wide suspension isn't really network wide (For real, this time, most likely)

Tags: support, bug, account-suspension, network-wide-suspension

Unlike what's being reported in [User is suspended network-wide, except not really](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/257498/user-is-suspended-network-wide-except-not-really) and [Account said to be suspended network-wide, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353813/account-said-to-be-suspended-network-wide-but-its-not), which are due to moderators manually lifting the suspensions, [this user](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/177247/zombo) is showing as being network wide suspended when in reality they're suspended on "only" five sites, and have an active account ([confirmed by one of the sites mods](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/9219543#9219543)) on 127 (!) sites. If a [CM](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/40353/stack-exchange-glossary-dictionary-of-commonly-used-terms/40354#40354) or moderators manually unsuspended on so many sites, kudos to them, but it looks like it's something different here.

What is going on? And can the bug(s) please be fixed?

---

**NOTE**: I am not asking why that user got a network (?) wide suspension or challenging that decision, just reporting the bug with the message and/or them actually suspended over the whole network.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Account said to be suspended network-wide, but it's not](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/353813/account-said-to-be-suspended-network-wide-but-its-not)

Comment: @Justin doubt it, I really can't imagine mods on 127 sites manually unsuspending the user.

Comment: There is certainly nothing different going on here. In this case, the user just happened to have accounts on 127 other sites. Essentially, the answer to the duplicate I linked applies here too. See also: [How can a network-wide suspension be not entirely network-wide?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323434/how-can-a-network-wide-suspension-be-not-entirely-network-wide). But let's see what staff/moderators have to say..

Comment: @Justin yes there is something different, the amount of accounts. I can't see any reason for such odd behavior of suspending all 132, then removing 127. Why not suspend on those 5 sites and be done with it? So, looks like some bug in action here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is the purpose of network-wide suspension if the regular mod can unsuspend the user on specific site?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/323442/282094), specifically that answer.

Comment: @Shadow: Note that the user has been suspended for **more than** 365 years on those 5 sites. This is only possible with a [network-wide suspension](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125268/my-account-has-been-temporarily-suspended-what-does-that-mean#:~:text=simply%20counting%201.-,What%20is%20a%20network%2Dwide%20suspension%3F,-A%20network%2Dwide).

Comment: @Justin I don't doubt there is network wide suspension. And it's 6 and half years, at least here, didn't check the other sites. Here it says "The suspension period ends on Dec 15, 2028 at 3:38".

Comment: Oops, I meant 365 *days*.

Comment: @Justin well, pretty sure there was actually a user who is suspended until 9999 or so, hence I thought you're serious. lol. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This user wasn't manually unsuspended anywhere, but due to a series of merge events that I won't go into in public, the account isn't technically network-suspended right now despite some of the profiles still having longer suspensions. The CM team can decide what they want to do about this case on Tuesday, if anything.

But there is no bug here. Possibly a misunderstanding of how the system would handle this. The system is working as designed in a weird situation.

Comment: "there is no bug here" - I disagree. Seeing clear message "This account is temporarily suspended network-wide" while it's not network wide is a bug. Maybe just wording, but still, a bug. Thanks for the quick answer!

Comment: Unfortunately it is just static text recorded at the time of the suspension and not tied to any indicator of the account actually being suspended network-wide. E.g. instead of recording "to cool down" as the abusive suspension reason would, it just records "network-wide" and calls it good.

Comment: I see. So feature request is needed to change that, as it's really not ideal. :/

Comment: I highly doubt anyone would invest time trying to do that when it affects only a few user profiles, assuming there's even more than this one. I honestly don't see why it even matters.

Comment: Would you say the proces of account merging, the one mere mortals of the CM team follow, not the technical specs, needs to be edited to factor suspensions into it? To me this sounds like a suspended and a regular account got merged and the user got mostly unsuspended because of that. While that might ofcourse have been intentional, it might be a good attention point in the procedure for merging accounts.

Comment: @Luuklag No unsuspensions ever occur as part of a merge. The unsuspended profiles were not suspended when the merge took place, the suspended ones were. I can't really explain the details, but this particular case is very far from a normal merge and trying to automatically handle it would probably have messed it up even more. I'm guessing the CM wasn't even aware one of the accounts was network suspended.

Comment: @animuson I wasn't suggesting any automation on that part, more of a "pay extra attention" point in the workflow followed when merging accounts. Although an automated check if there are any current suspensions could be useful to reduce the workload compared to manually checking all profiles in a merge.

Comment: @Luuklag We tend to only pay attention when we expect the account to remain suspended for some reason. It's not tough to check whether all profiles were suspended after a merge - it's just a page refresh. But if that wasn't the purpose of a merge, then I can't imagine any amount of process change would make a difference.

Comment: "I honestly don't see why it even matters" - because something is wrong. Message is misleading (saying something that isn't correct). No matter if it affects one user or a billion, something is wrong. Simple as that.